# DataGridView Save to Database on CellValueChanged Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ado.net

I'm trying to save changes on multiple datagridviews back to my database automatically as users make changes.  The code I have works fine if I tie it to a button click event, but not when I tie it to a cellvaluechanged event.  Any ideas?  It still steps through the code, and it's not throwing any errors, it just doesn't update the database.

```
Private dgv1_Source As New BindingSource()
Private dgv1_Adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()
Private dgv2_Source As New BindingSource()
Private dgv2_Adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()
Private dgv3_Source As New BindingSource()
Private dgv3_Adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()
Private dgv4_Source As New BindingSource()
Private dgv4_Adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()

Private Sub MainLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Grid 1
    dgv1.DataSource = dgv1_Source
    Dim selectCommand As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
    dgv1_Adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, SQL_ConnectionString)
    Dim commandBuilder As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(dgv1_Adapter)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dgv1_Adapter.Fill(table)
    dgv1_Source.DataSource = table

    'Grid 2
    dgv2.DataSource = dgv2_Source
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table2"
    dgv2_Adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, SQL_ConnectionString)
    commandBuilder = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(dgv2_Adapter)
    table = New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dgv2_Adapter.Fill(table)
    dgv2_Source.DataSource = table

    'Grid 3
    dgv3.DataSource = dgv3_Source
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table3"
    dgv3_Adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, SQL_ConnectionString)
    commandBuilder = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(dgv3_Adapter)
    table = New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dgv3_Adapter.Fill(table)
    dgv3_Source.DataSource = table

    'Grid 4
    dgv4.DataSource = dgv4_Source
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table4"
    dgv4_Adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, SQL_ConnectionString)
    commandBuilder = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(dgv4_Adapter)
    table = New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dgv4_Adapter.Fill(table)
    dgv4_Source.DataSource = table

End Sub
Private Sub CellValueChangedEvent(ByVal sender As DataGridView, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellValueChanged, dgv2.CellValueChanged, _
    dgv3.CellValueChanged, dgv4.CellValueChanged

    Try
        'Perform Calculations
        SaveAll() 'This one does not work.  No errors are thrown.
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub ButtonClickEvent() Handles Button1.Click
    SaveAll() 'This one works
End Sub
Private Sub SaveAll()
    dgv1_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv1_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv2_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv2_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv3_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv3_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv4_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv4_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this code and it fixed the problem.

```
Private Sub SaveAll()
    dgv1_Source.EndEdit()
    dgv2_Source.EndEdit()
    dgv3_Source.EndEdit()
    dgv4_Source.EndEdit()

    dgv1_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv1_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv2_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv2_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv3_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv3_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
    dgv4_Adapter.Update(CType(dgv4_Source.DataSource, DataTable))
End Sub
```